# launch activity after phone restart or manually turn power off or on

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

**how to launch an launch activity after phone restart or manually turn power off or on**

> i tried below codes but its working for only for unlocking phone but i also want to make it done for boot up manually or restart phone.

**below is code**

**application.class**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static SharedPreferences preferences;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public static String PASSWORD = "password";
    public static String IS_SET = "nothing";
    public static String MYPREF = "mypref";
    public String TAG = getClass().getName();

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        init();  
   }

    public void init() {
        preferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREF, 0);
        editor = preferences.edit();
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ScreenReceiver.class));

    }
}
```

**ScreenReceiver.class**

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     SharedPreferences preferences;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            System.out.println(intent.getAction());
            preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MYPREF, 0);
            if (preferences != null) {
                String lock = preferences.getString(IS_SET, null);
                if (lock != null) {
                    if (lock.equals("passcode")) {
                        gotopasslock(context, intent);

                    } else {
                        gotopatternlock(context, intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void gotopasslock(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Main.class);
                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent1);
            } else if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Intent myStarterIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
                myStarterIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(myStarterIntent);
            }
        }

        public void gotopatternlock(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, PatternLock.class);
                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent1);
            } else if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Intent myStarterIntent = new Intent(context, PatternLock.class);
                myStarterIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(myStarterIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Main.class**

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PinLockView mPinLockView;
    private IndicatorDots mIndicatorDots;
    private String TAG = getClass().getName();
    String oldPassword = "";
    String newPassword = "";
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // getSupportActionBar().hide();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_xml);
```

**menifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="label">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="face" />

        <activity android:name=".activities.ChooseActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <!--   <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />-->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.Home" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.Main"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.PatternLock"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true" />

        <!--<receiver
            android:name=".receiver.ScreenReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

        </receiver>-->
        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.ScreenReceiver"
            android:label="ScreenReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Google provides a lot of useful documentation for this. The basic gist is that you don't get to choose which ad specifically is displayed and when an ad request is sent, Google selects a bunch of ads that is suitable and selects the ad with the highest cost per click. If someone clicks on that ad, you get revenue.

Comment: @Sweeper what about vungle video ads? and app link i provided if u have time to overview the link can u plz tell me about the app earning

Comment: have you include  action android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED in manifest file for ScreenReceiver?

Comment: You have not included <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: i wll try @Krutik  but can u tell me..... i want to disable home button(soft and hard) ,back button and even user can do nothing (note :i want to ask u all about to implement like lock app)

Comment: i added permission as u told me ..but it launches activity after reboot completed fully... and i want to launch activity immediately phone reboots.(i noticed phone default screen lock launches immateriality ) ..

Comment: @Krutik  i will surely upvote once i got my ans as i expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137219/discussion-between-krutik-and-user7353543).

Answer (score 0):

Intent Action is missing.

To make a android activity launch after reboot, add following line in 
**AndroidManifest.xml**

**STEP 1**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

**Step 2:**

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receiver.ScreenReceiver"
    android:label="ScreenReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**NOTE:**

try to do code cleanup

Comment: see edited question,, i have implemented your answer  but when i reboot device so after one minuites  lock screen comes i want to show exact after the device reboot....lick in built  phone lock works.. and i also want to disable device  built-in lock